# How to convert Unicode string to Unicode Escape Sequence

Tags: php

I have some Unicode string in different languages like Arabic, Russian, etc.

I want to convert those Unicode string (جمع) to Unicode escape sequence (\u062c\u0645\u0639) using PHP.

Is there any function available for the same in PHP?

Comment: `json_encode` can easily do that for you, you’ll just have to strip off the double quotes it will add at the start and end.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe  Is that the only way?

Comment: How many ways do you need?

Answer (score 1):

[mb_convert_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) should work
like this:

```php
$string = 'جمع';
$encodedString = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-16BE', 'UTF-8');
```

if you want to check the string for anything first, since PHP7 you can write unicode in double quoted or heredoc strings like this:

```php
$unicodeString = "\u{062c}\u{0645}\u{0639}";
```